# How to rendering large list of data in React Select tag?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, selectinput

I have a large data coming from API.

```
const data = [{id: 1, name: 'a'},{id: 2, name: 'b'}, ....]
```

So, I want to render the data array into `select tag` which is like 2000+ objects in that array.

Is it possible to add `load more`?

Answer (score 0):

for implement the functionality of load more, it needs your api support pagination that you can get and show first nth item and load more for next pages, but I think in your case you should use [react-viewport-list](https://%20https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-viewport-list) in order to decrease renders.